# JWT sign in failing

Tags: node.js, reactjs, jwt

So I, have this code in my application. The app used to run fine a year ago. But now this code is failing. Everything else works fine, I have an ideal existing user id and email but the jwt sign is still failing. Can anyone tell me what can go wrong in this line code
"token = jwt.sign({userId: existingUser.id, email: existingUser.email},process.env.JWT_KEY {expiresIn: '1h'});"

```
  let token;
  try{
    console.log(existingUser);
    console.log(token)
    token = jwt.sign({userId: existingUser.id, email: existingUser.email},
       process.env.JWT_KEY,
       {expiresIn: '1h'});
    user.token = token;
    console.log(token);
  }catch(err){
    const error = new HttpError(
      'Logging in failed, please try again', 500
    );
    return next(error);
  }
```

Comment: Can you add the error log in the question?

Comment: print the `err` and share

Comment: Also, add the whole code here. Where you specify the existingUser?